# Guess the book/movie?

Tags: rebus, wordplay, computer-puzzle, language

What book am I talking about (this book has been made into a movie too)?

`'c'`lee_&_*le*_choke l8_(! - ial)ee

Once the puzzle has been solved it will be easy to understand how it fits.

Language, wordplay and basic programming stuff are included in this puzzle.

Hint 1:

> The first  `'c'` could have been any other letter, it makes no difference. The  `''` are important.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the following is the answer

> Charlie and the chocolate factory
>  'c' = char
>  lee = lie
>  & = and
>  le = the
>  choke l8 = chocolate
>  !-ial = factor
>  ee = y